# How to clear <p-autocomplete> after select value?

Tags: angular, primeng

I have autocomplete and table. After selecting an item, I need to add it to the array and remove it from the autocomplete.

Сode below doesn't work

```
<p-autoComplete
  (completeMethod)="getEmployees($event.query)"
  (onSelect)="change($event)"
  [(ngModel)]="employee"
  [suggestions]="employees"
  field="title"
  minLength="0"
></p-autoComplete>


change(newVal): void {
  if (!newVal) {
    return;
  }
  if (this.memberExists(newVal)) {
    this.employee = null;
    return;
  }
  this.document.employees.push(this.employee);
  this.employee = null;
}
```

employee is object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to empty the employee property to make it empty after the change. I have assign an empty value to it assuming it is string.

you can assign it to empty value depending upon its data type.

```js
change(newVal): void {
  if (!newVal) {
    return;
  }
  if (this.memberExists(newVal)) {
    this.commission = null;
    return;
  }
  this.document.commission.push(this.commission);
  this.commission = null;
  // reset employee value to make it empty.
  this.employee = {};
}
```

Comment: did it work ? Can you please describe the interface/structure of employee ?

Comment: I think it does't matter. Employee is just object with properties

Comment: then you can use this.employee = {} . Can you please create a stackblitz instance if it doesnot resolve your issue.